# Why are pointers not classified as an entity in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, entity, standards

I saw a quote in chapter 3, "Basic concepts", in the C++ standard.

Why are pointers not classified as an entity? even though references are included in it.

> An entity is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-ﬁeld, template, template specialization, namespace, or parameter pack.

Answer (score 5):

Pointers are objects, so they are entities.